# Special order items for our phone orders

Tags: orders, extensions, ce-1.9.0.1

From time to time we get phone orders for custom items that we need to special order. The issue is that we want to be able to use a custom item in magento and input the description and price on the spot when the order is created.

It's too much trouble to create a new item while the customer is on the phone.

How do I do this in Magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: May be you can create a simple product called "Special Item" with the custom option type "text" where you can specify all information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a simple product called "Special Item" with the custom option type "text" where you can easily specify all information while talking by phone. (moved from comment)